# Apache drops connection after 20 seconds

Tags: apache-http-server, timeout

Hi i have an apache server. Our client sometimes make slow requests, it makes the connection and takes over 20secs to send data.

Somehow there is any timout which drops this connections after 20 seconds and prints this in the access_log.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX- - [03/Jul/2015:14:53:15 +0200] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
```

The problem is that i cannot find the point where this is configured. And it seems not to be a .htaccess file, because the problem occours on ajp-mounted urls/vhosts too.

When i set

```
TimeOut 5
```

in the vhost config, the connection is dropped after 5 seconds, but when i set values higher than 20 it still dropps after 20secs.

We are using Suse 13.2 ... is there any OS based socket timeout?

Answer (score 4):

Ok the "problem" was the the module "reqtimeout" was enabled. If nothing is configured, it defaults to this value:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
```

which means headers must be started within 20 seconds

i've added a config line to our vhost

```
RequestReadTimeout header=300-360,MinRate=500 body=300-360,MinRate=500
```